# C - calculate address of pointer

Tags: c

I have program that put pointer `p` to some point and then calculate `p-*p`. The address of `p` is not specified in the program itself. How can I know what is `p` address?

```
typedef struct locals { int x; int y; } locals;
int main() {
    locals Z; char *p;
    Z.x = 0x00444342; Z.y = 0x01020304;
    p = ((char *)&Z) + 4;
    printf("%s\n", (p - *p));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no assumption for this task? Are there paddings in the struct? Is the system little-endian or big-endian?

Comment: warning: `p-*p` is not always valid.

Comment: No assumption at all

Comment: @RonenLevi: you can get the address of a pointer using the `%p` formatting specified, i.e. simply `printf("%p", p);`, or directly `printf("%p", &Z);`. Also, to get the address of `Z.y` you should simply write `p = &Z.y;`, what you're doing right now is far from being portable.

Comment: This is not my code. This is a questuon from old exam that ask : "what will be printed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain how to calculate the address with few assumptions:

1. The size of `int` is 4 bytes
2. The system is little-endian
3. There are no 0 paddings in the struct

Thus the `locals` memory layout is so that the first 4 bytes (`Z.x`) are

```
byte[0] = 0x42
byte[1] = 0x43
byte[2] = 0x44
byte[3] = 0x00
```

and the next 4 bytes (`Z.y`) are

```
byte[0] = 0x04
byte[1] = 0x03
byte[2] = 0x02
byte[3] = 0x01
```

Now for `p = ((cahr *)&Z) + 4`, `p` would point to the beginning of `Z` plus 4 bytes, which brings us to `byte[0]` of `Z.y`.

Now about

```
printf("%s\n", (p - *p));
```

`*p` would be the value of the first byte of `Z.y` which is `0x04`. And `printf` will get as the second argument address of `Z.y` - 4 bytes which is `byte[0]` of `Z.x`.

Thus the output of `printf` will be all characters till the first `'\0'` (which is the 3rd byte of `Z.x`):
ASCII 0x42 ASCII 0x43 ASCII 0x44:

```
BCD
```